# Using Swift classes inherited from Objective C libraries code in Objective C code

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoapods

I'm working on a Swift project, using couple of ObjC libraries.
One of them is [SWTableViewCell](https://github.com/CEWendel/SWTableViewCell). My app's lists' cells inherit from `SWTableViewCell`, a subclass of `UITableViewCell` that adds swiping action on cells.

Libraries are added with cocoapods.

I want to import some Swift code into ObjC, within my main project. The `project-Swift.h` is being generated as it should (every Swift class inheriting from NSObject, annotated as @objc is being included), but it contains errors:

```
project-Swift.h:135:31: Cannot find interface declaration for 'SWTableViewCell', superclass of 'MySWTableViewCell'; did you mean 'UITableViewCell'?
```

How to remedy this situation?
I need the header to be generated properly in order to use Swift classes in ObjC
My goal is either to ignore these classes, or let XCode that it needs to import additional header during `project-Swift.h`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should solve your problem:

1. Create a bridging header file in you project: File > New > File > (iOS or OS X) > Source > Header File
2. In your Objective-C bridging header file, import the needed Objective-C headers you want to expose to Swift: in your case you need `#import "SWTableViewCell.h"`

Comment: Why can't you add this #import to the swift header ?
(Just curios I still use obj-c never touched swift)

Comment: I just followed the approach proposed by [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html). Which Swift header do you mean? Swift does not use header files as Objectve-C.

Comment: No headers in Swift ?! wow okay :-) now I learned something new about this beast ! thanks

Comment: @user3351949: If you can spend some time learning the essential concepts of Swift I would strongly recommend doing that. I come from the Android/Java side and always struggled a bit with Objective-C. But with Swift you get things done in a much simpler way. But as usual the learning curve of new concepts might seem a hurdle at the beginning.